# Final and strongly final objects in Higher Topos Theory

Tags: higher-category-theory, higher-algebra

Lurie introduced in subchapter 1.2.12 of his [Higher Topos Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608040)
the notion of *final* and *strongly final* objects:

**Definition 1.2.12.1.** let $\mathcal{C}$ be a topological category (e.g. simplicial cats,
simplicial set).
An object $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is *final* if for each $Y \in \mathcal{C}$,
the mapping space $\text{Map}_{h\mathcal{C}}(Y,X)$
regarded itself as object in associated homotopy category $h\mathcal{C}$
is *weakly contractible*, that is a final object (in ordinary category sense) in  $h\mathcal{C}$.

**Definition 1.2.12.3.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be now a simplicial set.
An object ("vertex") $X$
of $\mathcal{C}$ is strongly
final if the projection $p: \mathcal{C}/X \to \mathcal{C} $ is a
trivial fibration of simplicial sets.

The used slice $\mathcal{C}/X$ for a vertex $X: \Delta^0 \to C$ is a simplicial set
whose $n$-simplices are $f \in \text{Hom}_X(\Delta^n \ast \Delta^0,C)$
where the subscript $X$ says that these are subjected to condition
$f \vert _{\Delta^0} =X$ (Proposition 1.2.9.2)

Two *questions* about some properties of these definitions:

1. Why is object $X \in \mathcal{C}$ final if there is a *retraction*
   of ($h\mathcal{C}$-enriched)
   homotopy categories from $h\mathcal{C} \ast [0]$ to
   $h\mathcal{C}$ carrying the unique object of $[0]$ to $X$. In other words
   why the existence of such retraction implies that
   for each $Y \in \mathcal{C}$,
   the mapping space $\text{Map}_{h\mathcal{C}}(Y,X)$ is
   *weakly contractible* in above sense. (this statement
   in used in the proof of Corollary 1.2.12.5)
2. After *Definition 1.2.12.3.* of strongly
   final vertex $X$ is remarked that it's equivalent to that vertex
   $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is *strongly final* if and only if any map
   $f_0: \partial \Delta^n \to \mathcal{C}$ such that $f_0(n) =X$
   can be lifted to a map $f: \Delta^n \to \mathcal{C}$.

Why that' true? Applying Definition 1.2.12.3 above $X$ is strongly final if the natural
projection $p: \mathcal{C}/X \to \mathcal{C}$ is a trivial fibration of simplicial sets.
In other words if $p: \mathcal{C}/X \to \mathcal{C}$ has the
lifting property with respect to every inclusion
$\partial \Delta^n \subset \Delta^n $. This means that
the condition should be read as that
a map $f_0: \partial \Delta^n \to \mathcal{C}/X$, such that
$p \circ f_0: \partial \Delta^n \to \mathcal{C}$ extends to
$\overline{f}: \Delta^n \to \mathcal{C}$, extends to
a $f: \Delta^n \to \mathcal{C}/X$ with $p \circ f=\overline{f}$.

Equivalently using adjuncion from defining property of the slice
$\mathcal{C}/X$ we have

$$  \text{Hom}_{sSet}(S,\mathcal{C}/X) = 
\text{Hom}_X(S \ast \Delta^0,\mathcal{C}) $$

for any simplicial set $S$, the lifting property can be reformulated
in terms of lifting a
$f_0: \partial \Delta^n \ast \Delta^0 \to \mathcal{C}$
with $f_0 \vert _{\Delta^0} =X$ to a
$f: \Delta^n \ast \Delta^0 \to \mathcal{C}$. But this lifting
property is seemingly also not the same as the remark
after Definition 1.2.12.3 in the book I exposed in point *2.* Or is it in some implicit sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to ask this kind of questions on a critical reading! (They are also great exercises in unwinding the definitions to learn to work with simplicial sets, although in the first case I couldn't quite work it out.)

1. I actually think that this argument is not complete: if $\mathcal C$ is a simplicial set such that the inclusion $\mathcal C \to \mathcal C^{\triangleright}$ has a retraction $f \colon \mathcal C^{\triangleright} \to \mathcal C$, then $f([0])$ need not be final in $\mathcal C$. This already happens when $\mathcal C$ is the nerve of a $1$-category $\mathscr C$: the construction $\mathscr C^{\triangleright}$ (adjoin a new final object to $\mathscr C$) commutes with taking the nerve (see §1.2.8), and if $\mathscr C$ already contained a zero object $*$, then we may define $F \colon \mathscr C^{\triangleright} \to \mathscr C$ by taking $[0]$ to any fixed object $Y$ and taking the unique map $X \to [0]$ for $X \in \mathscr C^{\triangleright}$ to the zero map $F(X) \to * \to Y$ (where $F(X) = X$ if $X \in \mathscr C$ and $F(X) = Y$ if $X = [0]$).

   But this is easily fixed. Morally what is going on in this argument is that the trivial Kan fibration $\pi \colon \mathcal C_{/X} \to \mathcal C$ is a categorical equivalence: this follows from the existence of the Joyal model structure (Thm. 2.2.5.1) since it has the same class of cofibrations as the Kan–Quillen model structure. Since $\pi$ takes the final object $\{X \to X\}$ of $\mathcal C_{/X}$ to $X$ in $\mathcal C$, we conclude that $X$ is final.

   This argument relies on the existence (and explicit description) of the Joyal model structure, so instead Lurie tries to give a direct proof. As I said, I think that the proof is incomplete, and I don't immediately see if there is a low-tech argument that completes this proof.
2. Recall that $\Delta^n \star \Delta^0$ is isomorphic to $\Delta^{n+1}$, where $\Delta^n \star \varnothing \subseteq \Delta^n \star \Delta^0$ corresponds to $\Delta^{\{0,\ldots,n\}} \subseteq \Delta^{n+1}$ and $\varnothing \star \Delta^0 \subseteq \Delta^n \star \Delta^0$ to $\Delta^{\{n+1\}} \subseteq \Delta^{n+1}$. Under this identification, $(\partial \Delta^n) \star \Delta^0 \subseteq \Delta^n \star \Delta^0$ is the outer horn $\Lambda_{n+1}^{n+1} \subseteq \Delta^{n+1}$, and the forgetful functor $\mathcal C_{/X} \to \mathcal C$ is given by restricting $f \colon \Delta^{n+1} \to \mathscr C$ to $\Delta^{\{0,\ldots,n\}}$.

   In this language, the condition for trivial fibration that you spell out becomes the following: given $f_0 \colon \Lambda_{n+1}^{n+1} \to \mathcal C$ with $f_0(n+1) = X$ such that the restriction of $f_0$ to $\partial \Delta^{\{0,\ldots,n\}}$ extends to a map $\bar f \colon \Delta^{\{0,\ldots,n\}} \to \mathcal C$, there exists $f \colon \Delta^{n+1} \to \mathcal C$ with $f|_{\Delta^{\{0,\ldots,n\}}} = \bar f$ and $f|_{\Lambda_{n+1}^{n+1}} = f_0$. But
   $$\partial \Delta^{n+1} = \Lambda_{n+1}^{n+1} \underset{\partial \Delta^{\{0,\ldots,n\}}}\amalg \Delta^{\{0,\ldots,n\}},$$
   so this lifting criterion is exactly the condition that any map $F_0 \colon \partial \Delta^{n+1} \to \mathcal C$ with $F_0(n) = X$ extends to a map $F \colon \Delta^{n+1} \to \mathcal C$. $\square$

Comment: What is the relation between the mapping space in HTT and the [one in Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/tag/01J5)? I guess that a "down-to-earth" argument would unravel the definition of mapping spaces.

Comment: @Z.M final objects are defined in HTT by going to $h\mathcal C$, which in turn is defined as the homotopy category of $\mathfrak C[\mathcal C]$. It's not super explicit, and early chapters of HTT contain very few calculations directly with this category. So there's still work to do if you want to produce an explicit construction of $\operatorname{Map}_{h\mathcal C}(X,Y)$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that, as a simplicial set, mapping spaces are complicated, but for the homotopy category in HTT, only their weak homotopy type is concerned, thus there might be a relation to the simpler model in Kerodon. Are they invariant under categorical equivalences?

Comment: @Z.M I think HTT Corollary 4.2.1.8 answers your question.